# image processing with otsu method for java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, binary

Is there anyone who know about otsu method for java? can you explain the java implementation of otsu method for image processing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's an [Otsu Thresholding plugin](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/otsu-thresholding.html) for [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). If you don't want to use it in combination with ImageJ, you can always have a look at the source of the plugin, to see how it is implemented.

### EDIT

You could also look at the Java demo here: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html

Comment: actually I want to use it in android and is there any way without using ImageJ?

Answer (score 0):

May this help, it's pure java

http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/java-image-binarization/
http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html